# bash: differece between source and execution

Tags: bash, include

I have a bash script say

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
```

then there is a difference between `./script.sh` (output: `./script.sh`) and `source script.sh`(output: `-bash`).
I'm using `source`in some scripts but I'm not quite shure I always use it the right way.

What differences are there between these calls? (Is it, that `./` calls a subshell and `source` runs within the same shell?)

What other ways are there to call a subscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right:

`source scriptname` will execute the script in current shell

`./scriptname` will create a new shell and execute everything there.

also(*not related with question though*):

`source scriptname` and `. scriptname` are same but
`source scriptname` and `./scriptname` are not.

Otherways:

```
1) the extra one I mentioned above.

2) exec

3) within () in a script or cmdprompt
```